buildroot external.mk target with variable parameters not working
I would like to merge configuration from Makefile, for this I've updated external.mk and introduced this:
# Custom target to merge multiple defconfig files
.PHONY: merge
merge:
    @if [ -z "$(filter %_defconfig,$(MAKECMDGOALS))" ]; then \
        echo "No defconfig files provided. Usage: make merge a_defconfig b_defconfig ..."; \
        exit 1; \
    fi
    @echo "Merging configuration files: $(filter %_defconfig,$(MAKECMDGOALS))"

# Prevent Make from treating the defconfig files as targets
$(filter %_defconfig,$(MAKECMDGOALS)):
    @:

unfortunately, it doesn't work:
$ make merge a_defconfig b_defconfig
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'merge'.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:83: _all] Error 2

If I don't pass any target parameters it reasonably reports missing configs:
make merge 
No defconfig files provided. Usage: make merge a_defconfig b_defconfig ...
make[1]: *** [/tmp/buildroot/external.mk:17: merge] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:82: _all] Error 2

What am I doing wrong?

Did the parent script export the variables?

Yes, the reason was that import happens above %_defconfig of main Makefile, and it got overwritten. If my merge is done in a way to append _defconfig - works well.
